# Get user data from Spotify

Tags: spotify

How can I get user data from Spotify without login?

YouTube Data API, you can get user public data information if you know the Channel ID.

Is i possible to do it in the same way?

I have tried the following link with UserID but it requires authentication.
https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/{user_id}/playlists

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should check documents below

[Spotify documents](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-list-users-playlists/)

hope helps

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer but it doesn't work form me.
They saying in the document that if the scope is empty that mean that you can take the user public information and in my URL there is no scope.
moreover, in YouTube, you need to put the application ID in the key parameter in the URL and then you can get the information. I didn't anything like this in the documentation of Spotify.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to [fetch user's public playlists](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-list-users-playlists/) you need to authenticate the request.

The authentication is based on OAuth 2.0 and there are [several ways](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/) to obtain a token. On of them, the [Client Credentials flow](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#client-credentials-flow) doesn't involve a login form and you only need your `client_id` and `client_secret` to obtain a token.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.